# How to sum negative, positive and both based on given month in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create my own budget table with vba, but I have an issue.

I would like to sum my expenses, incomes and would like to see a balance.

It is working from a data sheet where both positive and negative amounts are listed in separated columns like bank account or cash. Creating the balance number is going well, but when I would like to see my incomes, so only the sum of the positive numbers by the given date it doesn't work.

It is counts each line where the amount is greater then 0 and ignore the month statement.

Could you please advise how can I solve this issue and see the given months expense?

```
dim ws2 as worksheet
set ws2 = worksheets("Data")

dim bk as double
dim ca as double

mon = MonthName(Month(Date))

For i = 2 To lastrow

  bk = ws2.Cells(i, 3)
  ca = ws2.Cells(i, 4)

  If mon = MonthName(Month(ws2.Cells(i, 1))) And bk < 0 Or ca < 0  Then
    Expenses = bk + ca + Expenses
  End If

Next i
```

Comment: I think you should use a formula for this.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you retyped this code, since `bk as double` won't compile...

Comment: yes, I did apologies for that

Comment: Show an example of your data

Comment: Date | bk | ca
:----- | -----: | :----:
03/05/17   | -10| 0
03/05/17   | -10| 0
03/06/17   | 0|+50
03/09/17   | +5|0
03/10/17   | 0|-5

Comment: Meanwhile I have found a solution it is works with the following:

If mon = MonthName(Month(ws2.Cells(i, 1))) And (bk Or ca) < 0  Then

Comment: Re your last comment:  `(bk Or ca) < 0` will perform a bitwise Or of `bk` and `ca` and test that number to see if it is less than 0.  So, if the two numbers being used were -7 and 10 it would calculate -5 and then test whether that was < 0.  Although this will work in your specific situation, it would be a bad habit to get into (especially if you then try something like `(bk And ca) = 0` and expect it to work, e.g. `(9 And 4) = 0` is `True`) - use `(bk < 0 Or ca < 0)` instead.

Comment: And if you want to do this without VBA, you could probably use `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1),A:A,"<"&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())+1,1))+SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,">="&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1),A:A,"<"&DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())+1,1))` - i.e. just sum the values in columns B and C where the date in column A is between the start and the end of the month.

Comment: Thank you very much for help and advice!